# Rolling dice application for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, formula, dice

I am making an iPhone dice application and I wanted to create a button so that if I click it, it will generate a random number between 1 and 6 on the UITextField.

Can anyone help me out and give me a mathematical formula to generate such number?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Objective-C, try:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int random_number = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
```

The `6` is needed because `arc4random() % n` results on a number from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: i am using xcode. do i need this inside the .m file or .h file?

Comment: You may define a random_number() method in the .h file and implement it on a .m file. Or your could write a C macro? It's been a while since I've used Xcode.

Comment: `#define randint(min, max) (arc4random() % ((max + 1) - min)) + min` gives you a random integer: [min, max]

Answer (score 0):

`#include <stdlib.h>`

`int r = arc4random() % 6;`

Results between 0 and 5. Adjust with a +1 for 1 to 6.

Comment: `% 5` will only give results between 0 and 4.